# Mixins errors, no-undef problem using Vue Js

Tags: vue.js

I'm working on a small project using Vue.js and I try to create a directive in a mixin file but i get an error message contain : `error  'ValidateMixin' is not defined  no-undef`

This is my code (my component) :

```
<script>
import { ValidateMixin } from '../../mixins/ValidateMixin.js'
    export default {
        mixins: [ValidateMixin],
        data() {
            return {
                errors: {}
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

This is my Mixins File :

```
 export default ValidateMixin = {
  data: () => ({
    errors: {},
  }),
  directives: {
    validate: {
      bind(el, _, vnode) {
        el.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
          const vm = vnode.context;
          vm.errors = Object.assign({}, vm.errors, {
            [el.name]: e.target.validationMessage,
          });
        });
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mixed the named export syntax with the default export.  Since you're using a named import, here's the proper named export syntax:

```js
export const ValidateMixin = {
...
}
```

---

If you wanted the `default` export it would be:

```js
export default {
...
}
```

With this import:

```js
import ValidateMixin from '../../mixins/ValidateMixin.js'
```

Comment: can you write me an example please @Dan

Comment: Basically you only need to change the keyword `default` to `const`, nothing else.  Is this what you tried?